# How to parse empty tag from dom parser to use php webservice

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

In my xml there can be empty tags like `</title>`.

The problem is that when I parse the xml, I am getting null pointer exception when I reach this line in the xml.

How should I check tags like this in my parsing file?

```
ArrayList<String>textcomment = new ArrayList<String>();         
for(int i = 0;i<nl.getLength();i++) 
{   
    Element e = (Element)nl.item(i);
    // crash on this string find first time a value and second time find </no_of_comments> 
    String noOfcomment = e.getElementsByTagName("no_of_comments").item(0).getFirstChild ().getNodeValue(); 
    aryNoOfcomment.add(i, noOfcomment);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the line with problem?

It's this line?

```
String noOfcomment = e.getElementsByTagName ("no_of_comments"). item (0). getFirstChild (). getNodeValue ();
```

You are getting everything in the same line, so you don't check if one of them was null.

You can separate and then check if the result is null, like this:

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();
NodeList nl = e.getElementsByTagName ("no_of_comments");
if(nl != null){
    for(int i = 0;i<nl.getLength();i++) 
    {   
        Node n = nl.item(i).getFirstChild();
        if(n!=null){
             String value = n.getNodeValue();
             yourList.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to add value string in the arraylist

Comment: ok...but sir breakpoint is not working on this position arraylist and can i add this arraylist into the array ..please help me sir...

Comment: See if works now. But my friend, I don't like to use Elements to read XML... You can get better solutions in the Internet. You can look for a lib XStream, isn't to painfully to read a XML, but maybe it's a little slow than XMLStreamWriter, then google this: XMLStreamWriter

Comment: ok....you provided better solution for null tag value...i m  happy for your response ..thanks for this successfull response...

Answer (score 0):

for parsing you can use this...

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(dir); 
builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(); 
doc =  builder.parse(fi);

NodeList nlorgid = doc.getElementsByTagName("Organization");
String orgidfromxml = ((Element)nlorgid.item(0)).getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(" organization id from xml is "+orgidfromxml);
```